# Codeigniter Recursive Category Menu with Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, recursion

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_name_sef` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need help for my recursive codeigniter function.

**Below is my function code:**

```
function categories($parent_id = 0)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id)->order_by('cat_name', 'ASC')->get('category');
        $html = '';
        foreach ($sql->result() as $row)
        {
            $this->db->where('parent_id', $row->cat_id);
            if ($this->db->count_all_results('category') != 0)
            {
                $html .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row->cat_name . '</a>';
                $html .= $this->categories($row->cat_id);
            }
            else $html .= '<ul><li>' . anchor(array('category', $row->cat_id, $row->cat_name_sef), $row->cat_name) . '</li></ul>';
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

**This function simple output is like below:**

```
<li><a href="#">Smartphones</a>
    <ul><li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/1/apple">Apple</a></li></ul></li>
    <ul><li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/2/samsung">Samsung</a></li></ul></li>
    <ul><li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/3/motorola">Motorola</a></li></ul></li>
    <ul><li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/4/nokia">Nokia</a></li></ul></li>
```

**I want to do this output as like below:**

```
                <li><a href="#">Smartphones</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/1/apple">Apple</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/2/samsung">Samsung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/3/motorola">Motorola</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/project/index.php/category/4/nokia">Nokia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Hope that I explain my issue. Thank you so much for advice.

Comment: Post table structure also. This (your problem) is easy task to do you should be albe to figure it out by yourself. You dont need recursion for this at all. Two `foreach()` and you are done...

Comment: Database table added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this. lets start (add your html yourself)

this should work. It is not recusrive because there is no point!

```
$sql = $this->db->order_by('cat_name', 'ASC')->get('category'); //grab all categories and subcategories together!

foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {

    if ($row->parent_id == '0') {
        //we have a category
        echo $row->cat_name;

        foreach ($sql->result() as $subcat) {

            if ($subcat->parent_id == $row->cat_id) {

                //we have a subcategory
                echo $subcat->cat_name;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

EDIT

```
$html = ""; //init

foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
    $html .= "<li>";

    if ($row->parent_id == '0') {
        //we have a category
        $html .= "<a>" . $row->cat_name . "</a>";
        $html .= "<ul>";
        foreach ($sql->result() as $subcat) {

            if ($subcat->parent_id == $row->cat_id) {
                //we have a subcategory
                $html .= "<li><a>".$subcat->cat_name."</a></li>";
            }

        }
        $html .= "</ul>";

    }

    $html .= "</li>";

}
```

Comment: I need HTML help in recursive function :)
Please check <ul> and <li> structure, it is not as I want.

Comment: You are such a lazy person! Next time please do your research and at least try out answer provided! I am 100% sure you would figure it out yourself.

Comment: LOL after writing so much codes my brain stop working you know sometimes you need second eyes. Thank you so much hugs.

Comment: Do you have any idea for why this query returns 3 times blank <li></li><li></li><li></li> then showing normal results?

Comment: yes, wrong data in table... empty or something, my code is to give you an idea you must tweak it for your needs you can add `if ($row->cat_name == "") continue;` and in second loop `if ($subcat->cat_name == "") continue 2;`